# retrieve file path of shared object (linux)

Tags: linux, api, path, shared-libraries

Can I retrieve the file path of a loaded shared object in Linux?

(like on Windows there is an API GetModuleFileNameEx which returns the file path
given the module load address).

Also, can I get the load address of a shared object on Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way for you to do both is to parse /proc/self/maps.  That gives you both the virtual address ranges and mapped files.  Fair word of warning, though: not all of the filenames are files!

Comment: Since you're new here, you should up-vote if you think this is helpful (you can't until you get 10 reputation), or mark this as an answer if it solves your problem.